# How can I access current request in appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When in AppEngine's `handler` code I can access current request by `self.request`, is there a way to access it outside of handler code? Without passing `self.request` through all function calls.
Is there some thread local reference to current request?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Why would you need this, im curious?

Comment: I'm want to generate a callback url to some other handler and I need `self.request.host_url` for that

Comment: You can also use [uri_for()](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.uri_for) with the `_full` argument to keep from joining the parts yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
request = webapp2.get_request()
host_url = request.host_url
```

Docs: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.get_request